# How to get the theme that comes with the component in Flutter

Tags: flutter

How to get the theme that comes with the component in `Flutter`, such as `TextFormField`, how do I get the style that comes with his default `decoration`

I tried the following way, but the obtained theme attributes is **null**

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: TestPage(),
    );
  }
}

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var inputTheme = Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme;
    print(inputTheme.labelStyle); // is null
    print(inputTheme.fillColor); // is null
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: TextFormField(),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You could be set default value in ThemeData

Answer (score 1):

`Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme`

will get you the theme thats used with InputField

`Theme.of(context)`

will get you everything related to your app theme

try `copyWith()` and `apply()` to play around or apply the theme to a component

`Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme.copyWith();`

Comment: I have tried this method, but the theme attributes obtained is null

Comment: null!!, if you have trying to apply the obtained attribute, call apply

Comment: Use MaterialApp as root widget

Answer (score 1):

Some themes depends on the state of the widget itself. That is the case for `InputDecoration`.

To get the internal theme of a widget what you need is to either get this property if the widget exposes it (which is rare), or intercept it somehow by overriding the class and methods and getting the theme after it is created. That is difficult because usually it runs after the build.

One option is to look at the source code of the widget and copy the code that build the theme into your own code.

For example for InputDecoration.:

```dart
TextStyle _getHelperStyle(ThemeData themeData) {
    final Color color = decoration!.enabled ? themeData.hintColor : Colors.transparent;
    return themeData.textTheme.caption!.copyWith(color: color).merge(decoration!.helperStyle);
  }
```

Another option is to create your own theme, set the properties you need and get them after.

Answer (score 0):

Is the parent of TestPage a `MaterialApp` widget?
It should look something like this:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'YOUR APP NAME',
      theme: ThemeData( //can be omitted if you want the default theme
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: TestPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT:

If no `InputDecorationTheme` is passed to your `ThemeData` flutter will pass an 'empty' InputDecorationTheme. You can change it for your entire app by creating a ThemeData object and passing it your own InputDecorationTheme.

For example:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'YOUR APP NAME',
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
          labelStyle: TextStyle(), //your custom label style
          fillColor: Colors.orange  //your colour of preference
        ),
      ),
      home: TestPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Or pass an `InputDecoration` object to your `TextFormField` directly

```dart
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    //change what you want in here
  )
)
```

Comment: As you said ，The parent component is `MaterialApp`